# quotation mark inside variable

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

i'm trying to do very simple thing:
store quotation mark (`"` or `'`) inside variable **on javascript event** 
(for example: onerror (img element))

my code:

```
<img onerror="var m ='"';  document.write(m);">
```

or:

```
<img onerror='var m = "'";  document.write(m);'>
```

I do not need to explain why this code does not work(the attribute)...

(onerror=`"`var m ='`"`'; document.write(m);`"`>)

**note**: i can't use `charAt` or `fromcharcode` i'm trying to do it without any function (**alternatives**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape it with a backslash `\"`, i.e. `... onerror="var m='\"'; ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function as a handler of your event and use it that way.

```
<script>
   function onImgError() {
      var m ='"';
      document.write(m);"
   }
</script>

<img onerror="onImgError()">
```